# Do the 787 Flight Spoilers have variable deployment when using the Speedbrake?

Tags: boeing, spoilers

On the Boeing 787 (other Boeing models welcome too) while in-flight and/or on the ground do the SpeedBrakes/Spoilers have a variable amount of deployment (in angle) between the "ARMED" and "UP" settings? If you have a reference I'd be interested.

[image: 787 Speed Brake]

Comment: You are correct I meant 787. Title updated.

Comment: As stated in the answer "The angle of the spoilers varies continuously as the speedbrake lever is pulled aft. AFAIK, this is true for every Boeing model (and also Airbus)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle of the spoilers varies continuously as the speedbrake lever is pulled aft. AFAIK, this is true for every Boeing model (and also Airbus).

On the Boeing 737 NG the actual angles vary as follows (note that ground spoilers only extend on ground, as the name suggests):

> | Speedbrake lever angle | Detent | Flight Spoiler Position | Ground Spoiler Position |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> |  |  | (Nos. 2,3,10&11 / 4,5,8&9) | (Nos. 6&7 / 1&12) |
> | 0 | DOWN | 0 | 0 |
> | 4 | ARMED | 0 | 0 |
> | 5-8 | - | Start to move | 0 |
> | 29 | - | Between 0 and 20/22.5 | 52 / 60 |
> | 35.5 | FLIGHT | 19.5 / 24.5 | 52 / 60 |
> | 48 | UP (no detent) | 33 / 38 | 52 / 60 |

<sup>([b737.org.uk](http://www.b737.org.uk/flightcontrols.htm#Spoilers_/_Speedbrakes) - Flight Controls - Spoilers / Speedbrakes)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the farther back the handle, the more extended they are. The slower you pull or push the handle, the more gradual the change in drag. Stow them slowly, it's a very smooth process. Stow or deploy them abruptly, you'll get a pretty noticeable bounce.

No source I can link to, but I do fly 737s, if that's worth anything.